# Representation of binary matrix with space complexity of O(n)

Tags: algorithm, matrix, data-structures

I have nxn binary matrices (i.e. a matrices whose elements are 0 or 1). Using a two dimensional array (that is, storing the value of each element) have a space complexity of O(n^2).

Is there any way to store them in a way such that the space complexity is O(n)? All operations like summation, subtraction, etc. is welcome.

The matrices are not sparse so using list of non-zero elements is out of question.

Comment: Is the question how you can store n^2 bits in O(n) space? It's not possible in general.

Comment: If the matrix is symmetric then it could _sort of_ be done. Aside from that the only route is a compression algorithm which can't provide a guarantee of the target size.

Comment: So is the answer to my "there is no way to do that"? Is it mathematically proven, intuitively proven, common sense, or just nobody has come up with a way to do that?

Comment: @LukeBriggs How can it be different for symmetric matrices?.

Comment: @MuhammadNizami "_Is it mathematically proven, intuitively proven, common sense_" Yes, all three :).

Comment: @AlexD only in the sense that the best part of half of the data can be ignored - Just be me to it there; I was just about to say _"Yes - all of the above"_ :P

Comment: _"Joey has a list of 16 numbers. Represent that whole list with a list of 4 numbers"_ - At a worst case, those 16 numbers are truly random. No compression can be achieved.

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. Saved me from wasting time looking for a solution.

Comment: @LukeBriggs But it is similar like saying "_if the matrix is `n x n/2` instead of `n x n`_". As far as big-O is concerned, these constants are irrelevant.

Comment: @LukeBriggs Not a particularly apt analogy, I'm afraid; I can "compress" any four naturals x,y,z,w into one natural without loss by computing, e.g., 2^x*3^y*5^z*7^w. You really need to talk about space, not just about "how many numbers there are", to account for bigger numbers taking more space to store faithfully.

Comment: @Alex I Agree; _"sort of be done"_ was a bad choice of wording; it was more a quick example of how a space saving could be made, rather than actually getting it to `O(n)`. 
@DanielWagner great point; that was just a rough analogy of course, i.e. _16 doubles_ or similar would be more accurate to the intention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not store an n x n binary matrix in O(n) space.
The proof is just [pigeonhole principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle).

Suppose you devise a way to store an arbitrary n x n binary matrix.
There are 2<sup>n x n</sup> possible binary matrices of such size.
If you use k bits for the storage, there would be 2<sup>k</sup> possible contents of your storage.
Now, if k < n x n, we have 2<sup>k</sup> < 2<sup>n x n</sup>, and by pigeonhole principle, there exist two different matrices (say, A and B) which are stored the same way (say, X is stored).
So, when you have that X stored, you can not say whether the matrix you actually intended to store was A or B (or maybe some other matrix).
Thus you cannot uniquely decode your storage back into the form of the stored matrix, which destroys the whole purpose of storing it.

Answer (score 1):

First `proof`: A `n*n` bit matrix has `n*n` states. However with a n-bit string you can only store n states. So unless `n>=n*n` (e.g. n=1), there is no way to encode `n*n` bits in an n bit sequence.

Second `proof`, less abstract but also less complete:
Imagine you have a 16*16 matrix with 256 bits, and somehow manage to store this in 16 bits.
Now, of course, your could take those 16 bits and store them in a 4x4 matrix, using your algorithm, resulting in 4bits. Now your store the 4 bits in 2x2 matrix and compress them in 2 bits.
--> Essentially, such an algorithm would be able to compress any imaginable amount of data in just 2 bits. While this is not an actual proof, it is still quite obvious that such an algorithm cannot exist.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it can guarantee you O(n) space, but you can look for a compression algorithm called LZW (Lempel-Ziv-Welch).

It's quite simple to code and it's easy to understand why and how it works, and it should work very well for binary arrays, and the biggest your matrix is, the best the compression rate will be.

---

Anyways, if you know some information about the matrix, you can try to represent it in an array somehow you can restore, for example:

if you matrix is 32x32 dimension, you can get any row of it and represent as a single `int`, so a whole row will become a single number and you may have your O(n)